# Prolog character string list product, can't figure out recursion

Tags: string, prolog, swi-prolog, cartesian-product

one product/3
one_product(+Nonterminal,+Cell,-Product)

this is the closest I've gotten but I can't get the string to multiply with the tail. I've done research on this for a whole week.

```
conca(String,[H|T],Product) :-
    string_concat(String,H,Combined),
    append([Combined],T,Product).
one_product(String,Cell,Product) :-
    conca(String,Cell,Product).
```

With that I get

```
?- one_product("A",["B","C"],What). 
What = ["AB", "C"].
```

A part of another attempt.

```
Product = String * H.
```

These are single case attempts.

```
conca([],[_],Product) :-
    Product = [].
conca(String,[],Product) :-
    Product = [].
```

These are examples

```
?- one_product([],["B"],What).
What = [].
?- one_product("A",["B"],What).
What = ["AB"].
?- one_product("A",["B","C"],What).
What = ["AB", "AC"].
?- one_product("A",[],What).
What = [].
```

You'll also notice a product with an empty cell is empty.

Comment: So with `one_product("A",["B,C"],L)` you would have `L=["ABC"]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't don't want to use `append/3` for something like this. You want a recursive list process:

```
one_product(_, [], []).
one_product(String, [H|T], [StringH|StringT]) :-
    string_concat(String, H, StringH),
    one_product(String, T, StringT).
```

This is a common pattern in Prolog and can be done using `maplist/3`:

```
one_product(String, StringList, Product) :-
    maplist(string_concat(String), StringList, Product).
```

This will concatenate (prepend) string `String` with every string element of list `StringList` resulting in list `Product`.

Now, the only issue in the above is with your case:

```
one_product([],["B"],What).
```

This case uses a list for the first argument rather than a string. Is that the intent? If so, you can treat it separately:

```
one_product([], _, []).
one_product(String, StringList, Product) :-
    string(String),
    maplist(string_concat(String), StringList, Product).
```

Comment: it leads to cell_products goes to two lists. ["AC", "AD", "BC", "BD"]